# Angular 2 data binding breaks

Tags: angular

I'm writing a small component which consists of multiple lines and each line consists of:

1. dropdown with two possible choices - name it "type"
2. input box - name it "key"
3. input box/dropdown depending on the "type" (value from first dropdown) - name it "value"

The expected behavior is:

1. When the user selects "Constant" from the first dropdown the 3rd element should be a input box. If it's "Variable" it should became a dropdown.
2. If the user inputs both "key" and "value" fields the new line should appear for another entry. Such behavior should be triggered whenever "key" or "value" changes.
3. If the user removes either "key" or "value" from the line that is not the last one, such line should be removed. This should happen only when the "key" or "value" loses focus.

I created something like this:
[sample on plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HVG5XHl8zLzy3vJPD1Um?p=preview)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<div *ngFor="let rec of records">
  <select style="width: 75px;" class="select-field" [(ngModel)]="rec.type" (ngModelChange)="onTypeChange(rec)">
    <option *ngFor="let type of rec.types">{{type}}</option>
  </select>

  <input type="text" class="input-fields" [(ngModel)]="rec.key" (ngModelChange)="onValueChange(rec)" (blur)="onFocusLost(rec)"/>

  <input *ngIf="rec.type == 'Constant'" type="text" class="input-fields" [(ngModel)]="rec.value" (ngModelChange)="onValueChange(rec)" (blur)="onFocusLost(rec)"/>
  <span *ngIf="rec.type == 'Variable'">
      <select style="width: 75px;margin-left: 10px;" class="select-field" [(ngModel)]="rec.value" (ngModelChange)="onValueChange(rec)" (blur)="onFocusLost(rec)">
        <option></option>
        <option *ngFor="let field of fields">{{field}}</option>
      </select>
    </span>
</div>
  `,
})

export class App {
records: FieldSelectionRecord[] = [new FieldSelectionRecord()];
fields: string[] = ['foo1', 'foo2'];

  onTypeChange(record: FieldSelectionRecord) {
    record.value = "";
  }

  onValueChange(changedRecord: FieldSelectionRecord) {
    if (this.isLastElement(changedRecord) && this.isRecordFullyFilled(changedRecord)) {
      this.records.push(new FieldSelectionRecord());
    }
  }



  onFocusLost(changedRecord: FieldSelectionRecord) {
    if (!this.isLastElement(changedRecord) && !this.isRecordFullyFilled(changedRecord)) {
      this.records = this.records.filter(record => record != changedRecord);
    }
  }

  private isLastElement(record: FieldSelectionRecord): boolean {
    let index = this.records.indexOf(record);
    return this.records.length - 1 === index;
  }

  private isRecordFullyFilled(record: FieldSelectionRecord): boolean {
    return record.value.length > 0 && record.key.length > 0;
  }

}
```

Though it's not really working as expected. For example if you put both key and value the new line appears. When you click on the previous line and change its' type to variable it doesn't change "value" to dropdown. Also removing previous lines doesn't work always either. I was debugging it and I believe that the underlying values are being changed, but the view is not updated.

What's surprising is that I had a different component that was exactly the same without using "key" - only "type" and "value" and it's working perfectly. [Working sample here](https://plnkr.co/edit/xVhNCFOIhA5N1pXA6lVS?p=preview)

The only difference is missing of this line:

```
<input type="text" class="input-fields" [(ngModel)]="rec.key" (ngModelChange)="onValueChange(rec)" (blur)="onFocusLost(rec)"/>
```

and isRecordFullyFilled method.

I tried not to use two-way binding, but it didn't help either. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at browser console you can notice an error:

> VM3717 core.umd.js:3066 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Cannot read property
>   'length' of undefined

So try to check `value` before reading `length`

```
private isRecordFullyFilled(record: FieldSelectionRecord): boolean {
  return record.value && record.value.length > 0 && record.key.length > 0;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/MbmX6G5ufr5HNGWzyMZv?p=preview

Comment: So silly of me. However for some strange reason this error shows up on plnkr while on my local instance it doesn't log any error. Thanks a lot